# Cartesian product using spark

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have two sequences A and B. We want to generate a Boolean sequence where each element in A has a subsequence which occurs in B. For example:

```
a = ["abababab", "ccffccff", "123123", "56575656"]
b = ["ab", "55", "adfadf", "123", "5656"]
output = [True, False, True, True]
```

A and B do not fit in memory. One solution may be as follows:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("abababab", "ccffccff", "123123", "56575656"))
val b = sc.parallelize(List("ab", "55", "adfadf", "123", "5656"))

a.cartesian(b)
 .map({case (x,y) => (x, x contains y) })
 .reduceByKey(_ ||  _).map(w => w._1 + "," + w._2).saveAsTextFile("./output.txt")
```

One could appreciate that there is no need to compute the cartesian product because once we find a first couple of sequence that meets our condition we can stop the search. Take for example the first element of `A`. If we start iterating `B` from the beginning, the first element of `B` is a subsequence and therefore the output is `True`. In this case, we have been very lucky but in general there is no need to verify all combinations.

The question is: is there any other way to optimize this computation?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the short answer is 'NO' :)

I also don't think it's fair to compare what Spark does with *iterating*. You have to remember that Spark is for huge data set where sequential processing is not an option. It runs your function in parallel with potentially thousands of tasks executed concurrently on many different machines. And it does this to ensure that processing will finish in a reasonable time even if the first element of `A` matches the very *last* element of `B`.

In contrast, iterating or looping is a sequential operation comparing two elements at the time. It is well suited for small data sets, but not for huge data sets and definitely not for distributed processing.

Comment: But I wonder if there is other way to perform this computation by using a kind of short circuit. At the end, the computation is `f(a_1, b_1) || f(a_1, b_2) || ... || f(a_1, b_n)`. Imagine that instead of finding a subsequence you would need to perform a expensive operation. Do you really wish to do all these expensive operations when you already know the answer is true?

Comment: But the thing is, computation of `f(a_1, b_1)` may be carried out in taskA on machineX while `f(a_1, b_2)` is computed simultaneously in taskB on machineY and so forth. `f(a_1, b_2)` may very well evaluate to true, but this is not globally known until after all computations have completed and data is shuffled around in the `reduceByKey`.